# MS Access: Hiding Columns in Datasheet View using GUI

Tags: vba, forms, hide, ms-access-2016, datasheet

I am trying to set some columns in a datasheet view of a form as hidden when the form is loaded.

This is possible via VBA code like:

```
   Private Sub Form_Load()

      Me.Product_ID.ColumnHidden = True
      Me.Carrier_ID.ColumnHidden = True
      Me.Currency_ID.ColumnHidden = True

   End Sub
```

---

**However, Is there a way to do it in the form design by default, so we do not need this VBA code?**

I tried column width and/or visible properties but they do not work for datasheet view.

I am using Office360.

I read that this is used to be possible using the Format toolbar in GUI in old access versions.

My question:

Is that still available in access 2016?

If yes, where? cause I tried the Format ribbon when form is selected but every thing is dimmed and no commands for this purpose.

Comment: If you in normal view collapse/hide the columns manually and save the form and close it, the columns should remain hidden when you open the form again.

Comment: Thanks @Gustav: It worked. However it seems weird to me. If somebody else does not know about these hidden columns they have to search for it. Anyway. You can put your comment as an answer. Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, it is a bit backward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you in *normal* view *collapse/hide* the columns manually and save the form and close it, the columns should remain hidden when you open the form again.